# how do I call from a class that is in a file to display in another file containing the gl code using shaders (where both files are in jni folder)?

Tags: java, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface, opengl-es-2.0

How do I add my Cube in the glVertexArttribPointer in a .cpp file ?

I have a class Cube and another class Group which are subclass of another class Mesh. My cube class is in another file->group.cpp where we add the cube. Group is a subclass of Mesh class and Cube is also a subclass of Mesh class.
the gl code is in newproj.cpp where the line-> glVertexAttribPointer(gvPositionHandle, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, gTriangleVertices); displays the triangle since the vertices of the triangle are specified in the same file. So how do i display the cube's vertices and indices thru the gl code? Im new with shaders so I don't really understand how to display using shaders. 
Please guide me how to go about my Group class where I need to add and delete a cube.

P.S. I'm developing the project using OpenGL ES 2.0 on Eclipse + Ubuntu .
**What Im trying to do is convert the code I found in this tutorial (http://blog.jayway.com/2010/02/15/opengl-es-tutorial-for-android-%E2%80%93-part-v/) into C++ using JNI**

this is my code in **newproj.cpp** in my jni:

```
#include<string.h>
#include<jni.h>

#include<myheader.h>
#include<android/log.h>

#include <GLES2/gl2.h>
#include <GLES2/gl2ext.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define  LOG_TAG    "libgl2jni"
#define  LOGI(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO,LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)
#define  LOGE(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR,LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)

//Cube c;
//Mesh m;
    struct SMatrixStack {
        float lpfMatrix[16];
        float lpfInverse[16];
        bool bInverseUpToDate;
        SMatrixStack *lpsmsNext;
    };
    class CMatrix {
        public:
            CMatrix():lpsmsNext(NULL), bInverseUpToDate(false), bNormalUpToDate(false), bInverseNormalUpToDate(false) {LoadIdentity();};
            ~CMatrix() {SMatrixStack *tmp; while (lpsmsNext) {tmp = lpsmsNext; lpsmsNext = lpsmsNext->lpsmsNext; delete tmp;}};

            void LoadIdentity();
            void Rotate(float angle, float x, float y, float z);
            void Translate(float x, float y, float z);

        private:
            float lpfMatrix[16];
            float lpfInverse[16];
            bool bInverseUpToDate;
            bool bNormalUpToDate;
            bool bInverseNormalUpToDate;
            SMatrixStack *lpsmsNext;
            void Concatenate(float *m);
    };

    void CMatrix::LoadIdentity()
    {
        for(int i=0; i<16; i++)
        {
            lpfMatrix[i] = lpfInverse[i] = 0.0;
        }

        lpfMatrix[0] = lpfInverse[0] = 1.0;
        lpfMatrix[5] = lpfInverse[5] = 1.0;
        lpfMatrix[10]= lpfInverse[10]= 1.0;
        lpfMatrix[15]= lpfInverse[15]= 1.0;

        bInverseUpToDate = true;
    }

    void CMatrix::Concatenate(float *m)
    {
        float tm[16];
        int j;

        for(j=0; j<16; j++) tm[j] = 0.0f;
        tm[0] = tm[5] = tm[10] = tm[15] = 1.0f;

        for (int i=0; i<4; i++)
        {
            j = 4*i;
            tm[j+0] = m[j]*lpfMatrix[0] + m[j+1]*lpfMatrix[4] + m[j+2]*lpfMatrix[8] + m[j+3]*lpfMatrix[12];
            tm[j+1] = m[j]*lpfMatrix[1] + m[j+1]*lpfMatrix[5] + m[j+2]*lpfMatrix[9] + m[j+3]*lpfMatrix[13];
            tm[j+2] = m[j]*lpfMatrix[2] + m[j+1]*lpfMatrix[6] + m[j+2]*lpfMatrix[10]+ m[j+3]*lpfMatrix[14];
            tm[j+3] = m[j]*lpfMatrix[3] + m[j+1]*lpfMatrix[7] + m[j+2]*lpfMatrix[11]+ m[j+3]*lpfMatrix[15];
        }
        for (j=0;j<16;j++)  lpfMatrix[j] = tm[j];
        bInverseUpToDate = false;
    }
    void CMatrix::Rotate(float angle, float x, float y, float z)
    {
        float tm[16];
        int j;
        for(j=0; j<16; j++) tm[j] = 0.0f;
        tm[0] = tm[5] = tm[10] = tm[15] = 1.0f;

        float c = cos(angle);
        float s = sin(angle);
        float v = 1.0f - c;


        tm[0] = x*x*v + c;
        tm[1] = x*y*v - z*s;
        tm[2] = x*z*v + y*s;
        tm[4] = x*y*v + z*s;
        tm[5] = y*y*v + c;
        tm[6] = y*z*v - x*s;
        tm[8] = x*z*v - y*s;
        tm[9] = y*z*v + x*s;
        tm[10]= z*z*v + c;

        Concatenate(tm);
    }
    void CMatrix::Translate(float x, float y, float z)
    {
        float tm[16];
        int j;
        for(j=0; j<16; j++) tm[j] = 0.0;
        tm[0] = tm[5] = tm[10] = tm[15] = 1.0;

        tm[3] = x;
        tm[7] = y;
        tm[11]= z;

        Concatenate(tm);
    }

CMatrix cmobj1;

static void printGLString(const char *name, GLenum s) {
    const char *v = (const char *) glGetString(s);
    LOGI("GL %s = %s\n", name, v);
}

static void checkGlError(const char* op) {
    for (GLint error = glGetError(); error; error
            = glGetError()) {
        LOGI("after %s() glError (0x%x)\n", op, error);
    }
}

static const char gVertexShader[] =
    "attribute vec4 vPosition;\n"
    "void main() {\n"
    "  gl_Position = vPosition;\n"
    "}\n";

static const char gFragmentShader[] =
    "precision mediump float;\n"
    "void main() {\n"
    "  gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);\n"
    "}\n";

GLuint loadShader(GLenum shaderType, const char* pSource) {
    GLuint shader = glCreateShader(shaderType);
    if (shader) {
        glShaderSource(shader, 1, &pSource, NULL);
        glCompileShader(shader);
        GLint compiled = 0;
        glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &compiled);
        if (!compiled) {
            GLint infoLen = 0;
            glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &infoLen);
            if (infoLen) {
                char* buf = (char*) malloc(infoLen);
                if (buf) {
                    glGetShaderInfoLog(shader, infoLen, NULL, buf);
                    LOGE("Could not compile shader %d:\n%s\n",
                            shaderType, buf);
                    free(buf);
                }
                glDeleteShader(shader);
                shader = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return shader;
}

GLuint createProgram(const char* pVertexSource, const char* pFragmentSource) {
    GLuint vertexShader = loadShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, pVertexSource);
    if (!vertexShader) {
        return 0;
    }

    GLuint pixelShader = loadShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, pFragmentSource);
    if (!pixelShader) {
        return 0;
        }

    GLuint program = glCreateProgram();
    if (program) {
            glAttachShader(program, vertexShader);
            checkGlError("glAttachShader");
            glAttachShader(program, pixelShader);
            checkGlError("glAttachShader");
            glLinkProgram(program);
            GLint linkStatus = GL_FALSE;
            glGetProgramiv(program, GL_LINK_STATUS, &linkStatus);
            if (linkStatus != GL_TRUE) {
                GLint bufLength = 0;
                glGetProgramiv(program, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &bufLength);
                if (bufLength) {
                    char* buf = (char*) malloc(bufLength);
                    if (buf) {
                        glGetProgramInfoLog(program, bufLength, NULL, buf);
                        LOGE("Could not link program:\n%s\n", buf);
                        free(buf);
                    }
                }
                glDeleteProgram(program);
                program = 0;
            }
        }

    glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
    glDeleteShader(pixelShader);

    return program;

}

GLuint gProgram;
GLuint gvPositionHandle;


bool setupGraphics(int w, int h) {
    printGLString("Version", GL_VERSION);
    printGLString("Vendor", GL_VENDOR);
    printGLString("Renderer", GL_RENDERER);
    printGLString("Extensions", GL_EXTENSIONS);

    LOGI("setupGraphics(%d, %d)", w, h);
    gProgram = createProgram(gVertexShader, gFragmentShader);
    if (!gProgram) {
        LOGE("Could not create program.");
        return false;
    }
    gvPositionHandle = glGetAttribLocation(gProgram, "vPosition");
    checkGlError("glGetAttribLocation");
    LOGI("glGetAttribLocation(\"vPosition\") = %d\n", gvPositionHandle);

    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
    checkGlError("glViewport");
    return true;
}

const GLfloat gTriangleVertices[] = { 0.0f, 0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,0.5f, -0.5f };
//const GLfloat cubearray[]=c.Cube(2,2,2);

void renderFrame() {
    static float grey;
    grey += 0.01f;

    glClearColor(grey, grey, grey, 1.0f);
    checkGlError("glClearColor");
    glClear( GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    checkGlError("glClear");

    // Replace the current matrix with the identity matrix
    cmobj1.LoadIdentity();

    // Translates 4 units into the screen.
    cmobj1.Translate(0.0,0.0,-4.0);

    glUseProgram(gProgram);
    checkGlError("glUseProgram");
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glCullFace(GL_BACK);
    glVertexAttribPointer(gvPositionHandle, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, gTriangleVertices);
    //glVertexAttribPointer(gvPositionHandle, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, cubearray);
      checkGlError("glVertexAttribPointer");
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(gvPositionHandle);
    checkGlError("glEnableVertexAttribArray");
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
    checkGlError("glDrawArrays");
    // c.Cube(2,2,2);
    //root.draw();
}

extern "C"
{
    JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_newproj_pack_Tutcppmain_init(JNIEnv * env, jobject obj,  jint width, jint height);
    JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_newproj_pack_Tutcppmain_step(JNIEnv * env, jobject obj);

};

JNIEXPORT void Java_newproj_pack_Tutcppmain_init(JNIEnv * env, jobject obj,  jint width, jint height)
{
    setupGraphics(width, height);
}

JNIEXPORT void Java_newproj_pack_Tutcppmain_step(JNIEnv * env, jobject obj)
{
    //OpenGLRenderer Renderobj();
    renderFrame();
}
```

and this is my code **group.cpp** which is also in my jni:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <stdio.h>          // Header File For Standard Input/Output

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#include <GLES2/gl2.h>
#include <GLES2/gl2ext.h>
#include "string.h"
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
//#include<mesh.cpp>
//#include<myheader.h>

#include<iostream>
#include <stdio.h>          // Header File For Standard Input/Output

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <GLES2/gl2.h>
#include <GLES2/gl2ext.h>

#include "string.h"

struct SMatrixStack1 {
        float lpfMatrix[16];
        float lpfInverse[16];
        bool bInverseUpToDate;
        SMatrixStack1 *lpsmsNext;
    };
    class CMatrix1 {
        public:
            CMatrix1():lpsmsNext(NULL), bInverseUpToDate(false), bNormalUpToDate(false), bInverseNormalUpToDate(false) {LoadIdentity();};
            ~CMatrix1() {SMatrixStack1 *tmp; while (lpsmsNext) {tmp = lpsmsNext; lpsmsNext = lpsmsNext->lpsmsNext; delete tmp;}};

            void LoadIdentity();
            void Rotate(float angle, float x, float y, float z);
            void Translate(float x, float y, float z);

        private:
            float lpfMatrix[16];
            float lpfInverse[16];
            bool bInverseUpToDate;
            bool bNormalUpToDate;
            bool bInverseNormalUpToDate;
            SMatrixStack1 *lpsmsNext;
            void Concatenate(float *m);
    };

    void CMatrix1::LoadIdentity()
    {
        for(int i=0; i<16; i++)
        {
            lpfMatrix[i] = lpfInverse[i] = 0.0;
        }

        lpfMatrix[0] = lpfInverse[0] = 1.0;
        lpfMatrix[5] = lpfInverse[5] = 1.0;
        lpfMatrix[10]= lpfInverse[10]= 1.0;
        lpfMatrix[15]= lpfInverse[15]= 1.0;

        bInverseUpToDate = true;
    }

    void CMatrix1::Concatenate(float *m)
            {
        float tm[16];
        int j;

        for(j=0; j<16; j++) tm[j] = 0.0f;
        tm[0] = tm[5] = tm[10] = tm[15] = 1.0f;

        for (int i=0; i<4; i++)
        {
            j = 4*i;
            tm[j+0] = m[j]*lpfMatrix[0] + m[j+1]*lpfMatrix[4] + m[j+2]*lpfMatrix[8] + m[j+3]*lpfMatrix[12];
            tm[j+1] = m[j]*lpfMatrix[1] + m[j+1]*lpfMatrix[5] + m[j+2]*lpfMatrix[9] + m[j+3]*lpfMatrix[13];
            tm[j+2] = m[j]*lpfMatrix[2] + m[j+1]*lpfMatrix[6] + m[j+2]*lpfMatrix[10]+ m[j+3]*lpfMatrix[14];
            tm[j+3] = m[j]*lpfMatrix[3] + m[j+1]*lpfMatrix[7] + m[j+2]*lpfMatrix[11]+ m[j+3]*lpfMatrix[15];
        }
        for (j=0;j<16;j++)  lpfMatrix[j] = tm[j];
        bInverseUpToDate = false;
    }
    void CMatrix1::Rotate(float angle, float x, float y, float z)
    {
        float tm[16];
        int j;
        for(j=0; j<16; j++) tm[j] = 0.0f;
        tm[0] = tm[5] = tm[10] = tm[15] = 1.0f;

        float c = cos(angle);
        float s = sin(angle);
        float v = 1.0f - c;

        tm[0] = x*x*v + c;
        tm[1] = x*y*v - z*s;
        tm[2] = x*z*v + y*s;
        tm[4] = x*y*v + z*s;
        tm[5] = y*y*v + c;
        tm[6] = y*z*v - x*s;
        tm[8] = x*z*v - y*s;
        tm[9] = y*z*v + x*s;
        tm[10]= z*z*v + c;

        Concatenate(tm);
    }
    void CMatrix1::Translate(float x, float y, float z)
    {
        float tm[16];
        int j;
        for(j=0; j<16; j++) tm[j] = 0.0;
        tm[0] = tm[5] = tm[10] = tm[15] = 1.0;

        tm[3] = x;
        tm[7] = y;
        tm[11]= z;

        Concatenate(tm);
    }


class Mesh
{
    private:

        // Flat Color
        float rgba[4];
        int isize;
        int vsize;
        int csize;

        //CMatrix cmobj;
        GLuint program;


    public:

        Mesh();
        void draw();
        float *IBuffer;
        float *VBuffer;
        float *CBuffer;

        float x;
        float y;
        float z;

        CMatrix1 cmobj;
    protected:
        void setVertices(float &vertices, int vsize);
        void setIndices(short &indices, int isize);
        void setColor(float red, float green, float blue, float alpha);
        void setColors(float &colors, int csize);

};

Mesh::Mesh(){
    int isize=-1;
    float *p = rgba;

    // Smooth Colors
    *CBuffer = NULL;
    *VBuffer=NULL;
    *IBuffer=NULL;
    float rgba[]={ 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };
    GLuint program = glCreateProgram();
}

void Mesh:: draw()
{
    float rgba[]={ 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };
    float *vertices;
    // Rotate params.
        float rx = 0;

        float ry = 0;

        float rz = 0;

    // Counter-clockwise winding.
    glFrontFace(GL_CCW);
    // Enable face culling.
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    // What faces to remove with the face culling.
    glCullFace(GL_BACK);

/*
    static const char gVertexShader[] =
        "attribute vec4 a_Color;\n"
        "glVertexAttrib4f(a_Color, rgba[0], rgba[1], rgba[2], rgba[3]);"
        "varying vec4 v_Color;\n"
        "attribute vec4 a_Position;"
        "void main() {\n"
            "  v_Color = a_Color;\n"
        "a_Position = Projection * Modelview * Position;"
        "gl_Position=a_Position;"

        "}\n";
    static const char gFragmentShader[] =
        "precision mediump float;\n"
        "varying vec4 v_Color;\n"
        "void main() {\n"
        "  gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);\n"
        "gl_FragColor=v_Color;\n"
        "}\n";
*/
    static const char gVertexShader[] =
        "attribute vec4 vPosition;\n"
        "void main() {\n"
        "  gl_Position = vPosition;\n"
        "}\n";

    static const char gFragmentShader[] =
        "precision mediump float;\n"
        "void main() {\n"
        "  gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);\n"
        "}\n";
    GLuint positionSlot = glGetAttribLocation(program, "vPosition");
    glVertexAttrib4fv(0, rgba);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionSlot);

    GLsizei stride = sizeof(vertices);
    glVertexAttribPointer(positionSlot, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, stride, VBuffer);

    //glVertexAttribPointer(gvPositionHandle, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, gTriangleVertices);
    glClearColor(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    cmobj.Translate(x, y, z);
    cmobj.Rotate(rx, 1, 0, 0);
    cmobj.Rotate(ry, 0, 1, 0);
    cmobj.Rotate(rz, 0, 0, 1);

    // Point out the where the color buffer is.
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, isize,GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, IBuffer);
    // Disable the vertices buffer.
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(positionSlot);
    // Disable face culling.
    glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);

}


void Mesh::setVertices(float &vertices, int vsize)
{
    for(int v=0;v<vsize;v++)
    {
        VBuffer[v]=vertices;
    }
}

void Mesh::setIndices(short &indices, int isize)
{

    for(int i=0;i<isize;i++)
    {
        IBuffer[i]=indices;
    }
}

void Mesh::setColor(float red, float green, float blue, float alpha)
{
        // Setting the flat color.
        rgba[0] = red;
        rgba[1] = green;
        rgba[2] = blue;
        rgba[3] = alpha;
}

void Mesh::setColors(float &colors, int csize)
{

    for(int c=0; c<csize;c++){
        CBuffer[c]=colors;
    }
}


class Cube : Mesh
{
    public:
        Cube(float width, float height, float depth);
};


    Cube::Cube(float width, float height, float depth) {
        width /= 2;
        height /= 2;
        depth /= 2;

        float vertices[] =
        {
                -width, -height, -depth, // 0
                width, -height, -depth, // 1
                width, height, -depth, // 2
                -width, height, -depth, // 3
                -width, -height, depth, // 4
                width, -height, depth, // 5
                width, height, depth, // 6
                -width, height, depth, // 7
        };

        short indices[] = { 0, 4, 5, 0, 5, 1, 1, 5, 6, 1, 6, 2, 2, 6, 7, 2, 7,
                3, 3, 7, 4, 3, 4, 0, 4, 7, 6, 4, 6, 5, 3, 0, 1, 3, 1, 2, };



        int vsize=sizeof(vertices);
        int isize=sizeof(indices);

        setIndices(*indices,isize);
        setVertices(*vertices,vsize);


    }

class Group : Mesh {
public:
  void AddCube() {
      Cube c;
      c.Cube(2,2,2);

  }
  void drawobj(){
      Mesh m;
      m.draw();
  }
private:

};
vector<Group> grpobj;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an utter and thorough mess. You need to separate geometry from the shaders. So your class geometry should only export it's vertex and index lists and be able to

a) call glVertexAttribPointer() and glEnableVertexAttribArray() to prepare for rendering, and
b) render them using glDrawElements().

This is important because you may want to render one object on multiple places, then you do a) once and b) many times.

The shaders are whole different thing. You should have a class with shaders, that is able to compile shader source codes, and then to use the shaders. You may want to have more than a single shader in your application so you will compile the shaders once at startup, and then switch between them while drawing.

I am not going to fix your code. You would be better off writing a simple application (e.g. "first triangle" or "colored triangle" as they are often called), and improving your object design from there.